# truncate now() to only hour in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I truncate now() to get only upto hour precision in mysql?

In

```
select id from Run where submitTs <= now()  and submitTs >= (now()  - interval 1 hour);
```

I really want the records from 12.00 PM to 1 PM instead of 12.23 PM to 1.23 PM if I am running at 1.23 PM.

So how do I say

```
  submitTs<= truncate_to_hour(now())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try thsi query -

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  Run
WHERE
  DATE(submitTs) = CURDATE() AND
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM submitTs)
```

This query has better performance than first one -

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  Run
WHERE
  submitTs >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) HOUR AND
  submitTs < CURDATE() + INTERVAL EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) + 1 HOUR
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Run 
WHERE submitTs BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h'), ':00:00') AS DATETIME)
      AND CAST(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %h'), ':00:00') AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: I think you meant %Y-%m-%d %h ?

Answer (score -1):

I think some thing like this can help you to get hour of now():

```
HOUR(TIME(NOW())
```

Please see the reference at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html to get more date-time function in mysql.

Comment: Sorry I don't want only hour - I want now() with precision truncated to hour.